# Followup question: How to count individual bits using avx2

Tags: c++, intrinsics, avx2

Here is a function which takes an array of 64 bit integers and counts how many 1 bits are in each position. Using AVX2, it should be possible to do this for 16 bits simultaneously, but then each counter can only go up to 65536. The following code would count each block of 65500 values, but I am missing one critical operation: I cannot find a way to individually shift each number by a different count. Am I missing something? The comment in the code shows the spot. Ideally each number is loaded from memory, and split into 4 16-bit chunks. Each chunk can be processed on one 256-bit register. In order to count more than 64k, the counts would be stored in memory and added to a wider register.

```
void countHistBits4(const uint64_t p[], uint32_t n, uint32_t hist[64]) {
  uint16_t shifts[16] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
                                                8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
  uint16_t maskss[16] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                                                 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
    __m256i shift = _mm256_load_si256((__m256*)shifts);
        __m256i mask1 = _mm256_load_si256((__m256*)masks);
        for (uint32_t j = 0; j < n; j += 65500) {
            __m256i count1 = _mm256_setzero_si256();
            __m256i count2 = _mm256_setzero_si256();
            __m256i count3 = _mm256_setzero_si256();
            __m256i count4 = _mm256_setzero_si256();
            for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 65500; i++) {
                __m256i v1 = _mm256_set1_epi16(p[i] & 0xFFFF);
                __m256i v2 = _mm256_set1_epi16((p[i] >> 16) & 0xFFFF);
                __m256i v3 = _mm256_set1_epi16((p[i] >> 32) & 0xFFFF);
                __m256i v4 = _mm256_set1_epi16((p[i] >> 48) & 0xFFFF);

                // for each bit, right shift to the 1 position, and with 1
                // and add to the count
                
                // this isn't right. How to shift each 16 bit value by different const?
                // if that isn't possible, what is the approach?
                v1 = _mm256_srl_epi16(v1, shift);
                v2 = _mm256_srl_epi16(v2, shift);
                v3 = _mm256_srl_epi16(v3, shift);
                v4 = _mm256_srl_epi16(v4, shift);
                v1 = _mm256_and_si256(v1, mask1);
                count1 = _mm256_adds_epi16 (count1, v1);
                v2 = _mm256_and_si256(v2, mask1);
                count2 = _mm256_adds_epi16 (count2, v2);
                v3 = _mm256_and_si256(v3, mask1);
                count3 = _mm256_adds_epi16 (count3, v3);
                v4 = _mm256_and_si256(v4, mask1);
                count4 = _mm256_adds_epi16 (count4, v4);
            }
            // store and add into larger counters... 
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/mklarqvist/positional-popcount has working code for this, and the linked duplicates have other good strategies.  Closed as a duplicate based on the question title.

Comment: But for this strategy, AVX2 doesn't have `vpsrlvw`, only dword and qword sizes.  (AVX-512 does have it).  Instead of shifting the bit, *compare* to turn it into `0` / `-1`, and *subtract* that -1 from your counters.  `x & mask == mask` checks that the selected bit was set in that element, so use `_mm256_cmpeq_epi16` and `_mm256_subs_epi16`.

Comment: This also has the advantage of not needing a shift vector constant, like you would with AVX-512 variable-shifts or for a 32-bit-chunk version of this with [AVX2 `vpsrlvd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpsrlvw:vpsrlvd:vpsrlvq).  Of course, with AVX-512 you'd do something like [test-into-mask](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vptestmb:vptestmw:vptestmd:vptestmq) to directly set a mask from a per-element `x & mask != 0`, then do a merge-masked add.  Or no, with AVX-512 you'd use the data you're counting *as* a mask for this strategy, never broadcasting it in the first place.

Comment: Wait a minute: *the counts would be stored in memory and added to a wider register.* - Why memory?  Why not just widen horizontally to 32-bit with `_mm256_madd_epi16` (`vpmaddwd`) with `_mm256_set1_epi16(1)` in an outer loop, then reduce 4 vectors to 1 and `_mm256_add_epi32`. (To further widen to 64-bit counts, optionally unpack lo/hi with zeros and `_mm256_add_epi64` into a vector of 64-bit counters, which you hsum at the end.)  Also, if you're going to make sure you can't overflow, use normal `add` or `sub`, not saturating: it can run on more ports on some CPUs. (https://uops.info/)

Comment: (I probably should have posted this as an answer, but I already closed this question as a duplicate based on the title.  I don't think this strategy is optimal, so it's probably not what future readers should be doing anyway for this common well-studied problem.  Finishing your implementation of this strategy is useful as a learning exercise, though.)